# Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead gon gem and passing data from model into JS - in json format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I would like the names of my 'firms'to be passed into an auto completing typeahead on a form.

I am using twitter bootstrap and the gon gem to pass the data into Json and make it available to the js.

However i cannot get the field to respond, i dont think that the data is available to the form and do not understand why.

my firms controller does the following assigning the names of the firms to a gon variable.

```
gon.firms = Firm.all.map &:name
```

My Application.html.erb has the following in its header to make the gon variable available to js.

```
<%= include_gon %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $(.typeahead).typeahead({source:gon.firms});
    });
    </script>
```

Then I have the form that I would like assign the typeahead to, I have assigned the class="typeahead" to it.

```
<%= form_tag firms_path, :method => 'get', :class => 'typeahead'  do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'input-medium search-query', :placeholder => 'Firm name' %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil ,:class => 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

Finally the application.js file the relevant jquery as per the twitter bootstrap documentation.

```
$(function() {  
    $('.typeahead .input-medium search-query').typeahead({source:[gon.firms]});
}
```

My application .js also has the following libraries

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

I have checked that gon.firms is available as a variable, but the dev console has the following error

```
uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token
```

any ideas what may be causing this?

Is there anything obviously wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure `gon.firms` is populated as you expect (check in your web dev tool console). Then while you're there make sure there aren't js errors as you type in the box. Finally, as per [the docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead), it looks like you want to attach the plugin to the text field, not the form:

```
$('.typeahead .search-query').typeahead( { source: gon.firms } );
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to try and help me sort this, i shall have a bash at that and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

This is because gon.firms is a ruby array not a js array.

You can tranfer a string to js and then split it to a array like this:

```
$(function() {
    var col = "<%= @pon.firms.join(",") %>".split(",");
    $(".search-query").typeahead({ source: col });
});
```